# Shortcut for duplicating lines in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-2015, keyboard-shortcuts

I started relearning Unity again after a break. Before I use to work on monodevelop and i could easily copy above line down by Shift+Alt+Up/Down. But now i can't find anything similar in VS for Unity. I am working from Mac.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Find what the shortcut is using search bar on top of window.

This is for Windows but I believe Mac version has the same search bar.

As you can see on this picture, the default is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>, <kbd>V</kbd>.

[image]

You can also directly check if the command really exists in Tools/Options menu.

[image]

Comment: The search bar is not showing any duplicate command which is strange. I tried to search it before, it does show copy command but no duplicate command. The solution you gave works but i miss the copying line with up and down key.

Comment: I just added an alternative way.

Comment: There is no options in tools. there is visual studio>preferences>key bindings. I am using Visual studio Community if that helps. there is no key binding for duplicate nor i can make one.

Comment: You get the idea now, search for it, sorry but I have no Mac to test it out.

Comment: Yeah that's okay. My problem is solved with your solution.

Comment: Okay, that's great 